# In Granger causality test, what does very low p-value means when you know there is little correlation

Tags: time-series, similarities, cross-correlation, granger-causality

I am testing a comparison between two time series to see if/how a variable Xs interacts/affects variable Ys.

I have come across some cases where I use cross-correlation where I verify there is little correlation and anti-correlation but the p-values of these cases are like 0.00001.

According to what I understood the lower the p-value is the higher the chance of the Null hypothesis being false. However since the cross-correlation algorithm says there is little correlation between them, I find odd the p-value being so low.

So what I want to know is, in what situations this can happen or if low p-value can mean something else, or even if all my approach/logic is rubbish since I am self-learning and doing this for the first time so there a decent chance that might happen.

Comment: Testing whether $x \xrightarrow{Granger}y$ involves assessing the partial correlations between $y_t$ and $x_{s}$ where $s<t$, for one or more lags of $x$. So $x$ is lagged with respect to $y$. Can this explain the apparent paradox?

Comment: No, because even in the lagged areas obtained in cross-correlation I can't find high correlation values between the two time series

Comment: Could include the Granger causality test results and the cross correlation plot (or table) in your post?

Comment: Right now I can't post it, but for example I had on which had in which the highest value of cross relation for a lag was slightly less than 0.3 (which had a sort of log increase/decline that never was bellow 0 )and the p-value had 0.000015.

Comment: One explanation could be that partial correlation is higher than regular correlation, i.e. the regression $y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_s+u_t$ yields insignificant $\beta_1$ while $y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1' x_s+\alpha_1 y_s+v_t$ yields a significant $\beta_1'$. That could happen. For Granger causality test it is the partial correlation that matters.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, could you tell me though how could I very that on R. Since I don't think there is a function to verify the partial correlation between two time series

Comment: Partial correlation depends on what other variables you are considering. Run a regression model and check the coefficient significance – that will tell whether the partial correlation is significant. That is what the Granger causality test is doing. (So you already know the answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One explanation could be that partial correlation is higher than regular correlation, i.e. the regression

$$ y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_s+u_t $$

yields an insignificant $\beta_1$ while

$$ y_t=\beta_0+\beta'_1 x_s+\alpha_1 y_s+v_t $$

yields a significant $\beta'_1$. That could happen. For Granger causality test it is the partial correlation that matters.

> ould you tell me though how could I very that on R. Since I don't think there is a function to verify the partial correlation between two time series

Partial correlation depends on what other variables you are considering. Run a regression model and check the coefficient significance – that will tell whether the partial correlation is significant. That is what the Granger causality test is doing. (So you already know the answer.)

Comment: So having two distinct results, what sort of information could I obtain from them? That a correlation is possible but it's not certain?

Comment: Partial correlation and regular correlation are two different things, so there is no paradox to find one is large while another is small (or statistically significant vs. insignificant). You would pay attention to one versus another depending on what question you are trying to answer. E.g. for Granger causality you care about the partial one and you can ignore the regular one because the latter is simply not interesting w.r.t. the question you are trying to answer.

Comment: Ok. Since I am comparing two time series I was under the assumption that if I had a low P-Value I would at least find a significant correlation/anti-correlation in a cross-correlation function. Since cross-correlation values were so low for some cases I struggled to find why the P-value would be so low since I interpreted my cross correlation as if there was no relation between the time series.

Comment: Even if there is no relationship between $y$ and $x_1$, there may be a relationship between $y$ and $x_1$ when you also bring $x_2$ into play. Consider $y=(1,1,1,1)$ $x_1=(1,0,1,0)$ and $x_2=(0,1,0,1)$. Projecting $y$ on $x_1$ or $y$ on $x_2$ separately will do no good. However, projecting $y$ on $(x_1,x_2)$ will give a perfect fit. There is no paradox; it's just that context (the other variables that are included in the model) matters.